# How can I represent a symmetric matrix in CSR format?

Tags: sparse-matrix, numerical-methods, compression

Although I'm using C, the programming language and the code are irrelevant, I believe.

I want to represent a symmetric matrix in CSR format, for fast matrix-vector product.

The input stream I read from gives the upper-triangular part of the matrix only, number by number, left to right, row to row.

Example:

```
0 2 3 5
2 0 1 4
3 1 0 9
5 4 9 0
```

Input stream:

```
0 2 3 5 0 1 4 0 9 0
```

If I were to build a regular matrix from, say, two-dimensional array, it would be easy. All I need is the data I get. That's not the case for a CSR representation.

Comment: One idea I have is to create the transpose of the upper-triangular matrix. I wouldn't lose any  efficiency while doing the matrix-vector product.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was transpose the matrix in CSR. That way, the matrix-vector product is still efficient and easy to implement.

Building the transpose costs a lot of time, and also doubles the memory usage.

That's the best idea I could have. I appreciate any other.